# Select by Map Content

Tags: qgis, select

I have a QGIS project of species presence/absence in European countries (TDWG data). That's 84 species against 63 countries. For each species I've used the exact same map layer, used Categorize to colour each country the same then ticked the countries to indicate presence.
I now wish to extract that data in some way in order to create an 84 x 63 matrix (in a spreadsheet)
The "Filter Legend by Map Content" helpfully shortens the list of countries that I've ticked (displayed in the Layers window.) Is there a means of selecting just those items so that I can output the country presence list to a CSV

Comment: For me it's a bit unclear, whether you have 84 vector layers (one for each species) or just one with 84 columns.

Comment: What do you mean by "ticked the countries to indicate presence"? Do you mean that you have 63 layers (1 for each country and turned them on in the Layers Panel). If not perhaps include some screenshots to better illustrate what you have so far

Comment: One vector layer of 63 countries. Displayed 84 times as follows:

Comment: 1. Add group in layers panel, name it with taxon 2. Add countries vector layer 3. Properties, style categorised (column = country name) 4. Highlight all items in the list, right click and choose change colour 5. By default the tick box against all these items is set as "display", uncheck them all. 6. From research determine presence/absence of the taxon in each country and tick those that are present. By default all items are listed in the layers panel legend, ticked or not. Select  Filter Legend by Map Content